# something weird with samesite cookies

Tags: cookies, samesite

If you access to this url from google (you can search it as literally to find it quickly in SERP):
`https://www.b e b e m o v i l.com/inglesina-electa`
cookies politic will be shown (blue div) and if press "cerrar" it will make a cookie with flag "1" to prevent showing it again.  OK.

That cookie is created with php setcookie as `Samesite=Strict` and Path `/`, then `inglesina/` subfolder is valid for root path. OK

If , after pressing "Cerrar" button to accept cookies policies, you press F5 to update the page , woalaaa!  the message of cookie policies is being shown again (always).

The weird case is that if i access to the same url from adress bar of browser  (not from google) , all is working fine, but if i access from google, loop cookie message happens!

Of course if `samesite=None` it works fine, however i want it is `Strict`

Any idea please????

Comment: You want a cookie with `SameSite=Strict`. And you want the cookie to be available immediately after navigation to the page. These two wishes are contradictory.

Comment: Have a look at the techniques discussed [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/272425/is-using-two-cookies-one-lax-and-one-strict-a-way-to-improve-usability-without-c/272450#272450).

Comment: Heiko, the cookie is available just when i press "Accept Cookies", and ajax process sets the cookie.  Is it wrong?

Comment: Pop Up with cookies policies are shown after onload event (like all sites).  Then i a accept cookies, it will create a cookie with flag 1, to prevent to show it again.  How ever if you refresh de page with F5 that pop up is shown again.   It is weird that, (with already flag value = 1) if i refresh page, the pop up keeps showing up, like flag value of cookie was = 0 yet.

Answer (score 1):

If a website asks users whether they accept tracking cookies and stores the user decision in another cookie, that other cookie should *not*  have `SameSite=Strict`. Otherwise, the "decision cookie" will be suppressed when the user later navigates to the same site again, and they will be asked whether they accept cookies upon every navigation to it.

Consider complaining to the webmaster of a site that sets "decision cookies" with `SameSite=Strict`.

`SameSite=Strict` can be set as a countermeasure against cross-site request forgery ([csrf](/questions/tagged/csrf)), but it does not distinguish between unwanted effects (navigate to a site and unintentionally transfer money from your bank account) and desirable effects (navigate to a site and let it know that you accept its cookies).
See also [this question on Security StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/272425/is-using-two-cookies-one-lax-and-one-strict-a-way-to-improve-usability-without-c).

Comment: Ah ok ok. So cookie that is saved to "accept cookie policy" shouldn´t be "SameSite=Strict" , true? Then, when should we use "SameSite=Strict"?

Comment: See my augmented answer.